# Ruby Case Statement that keeps progressing

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to convert special symbols (*{W} {B} {U}* etc) to their respective color so I wrote a CASE but I'm thinking a case isn't what I need since it ends as soon as it finds a match.

```
print 'Test a Color'
color = gets.chomp

case color
when '{W}'
  puts 'White'
when '{R}'
  puts 'Red'
when '{G}'
  puts 'Green'
when '{U}'
  puts 'Blue'
when '{B}'
  puts 'Black'
end
```

*{B}* gets me *Black*, *{U}* gets my *Blue*. *{U}{B}* crashes it/returns nothing.
How would I go about letting it continue down the list?

Comment: Ruby case statements don't fall through like C switch statements.

Answer (score 7):

Check below.

```
print "Test a Color"
color = gets.chomp

hash = {
  '{W}' => 'White',
  '{R}' => 'Red'
}

# finding by regex and replace with what you want.
puts color.gsub(/\{.+?\}/){|k| hash[k] || k }
```

Comment: `gsub` accepts a hash already. `color.gsub Regexp.union(hash.keys), hash` would do.

Comment: You could use a more specific regex like `/\{[WR]\}/` to avoid the `|| k` fallback.

Comment: @Stefan or `hash` might have this fallback implemented as `default_proc`.

Comment: @xdazz Awesome approach, simple and clean. One question though - How could I make it so {W} {W} only outputs the word White once?

Comment: @DNorthrup use `scan` as shown in [CodeGnome's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40648773/477037) and call `colors.uniq`

Answer (score 2):

```
colors = {
  'W' => 'White',
  'R' => 'Red',
  'G' => 'Green',
  'U' => 'Blue',
  'B' => 'Black',
}

input.scan(/{(\w)}/).each { |abbreviation| puts colors[*abbreviation] }
```

Answer (score 2):

### Caveat

The following isn't the most efficient or idiomatic solution. However, it addresses your problem by making some simple improvements to your existing code while preserving your current semantics.

### Loop Over Your Case Statement

This solution reads standard input and converts it into an Array object stored in *colors*, and then loops over the case statement for each element of that array.

```rb
print "Test a Color: "
colors = gets.chomp.scan /\{[WRGUB]\}/
colors.each do |color|
  case color
  when "{W}"
    puts "White"
  when "{R}"
    puts "Red"
  when "{G}"
    puts "Green"
  when "{U}"
    puts "Blue"
  when "{B}"
    puts "Black"
  end
end
```

This will result in output similar to the following:

```
$ ruby colors.rb 
Test a Color: {W}{B}
White
Black
```

Answer (score 1):

While @xdazz’ answer does the trick, it is not quite ruby idiomatic:

```
hash = %w|W R G U B|.map { |e| "{#{e}}"}
                    .zip(%w|White Red Green Blue Black|)
                    .to_h

print "Test a Color"
# color = gets.chomp
color = "Hello, {W}, I am {B}!"
puts color.gsub(Regexp.union(hash.keys), hash)
#⇒ Hello, White, I am Black!
```

We use here [`String#gsub(pattern, hash)`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub).

Comment: Nice use of `gsub`, but the hash creation looks a bit weird ;-)

Comment: @Stefan Once I spent an hour chasing the `[`-instead-of-`{` in the same codepiece and since then I’d better write weird but DRY, than pretty but copy-pasted.

Comment: Fair enough :-)